# Entity Framework: how to model for bulk operations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-modeling

I have some entity classes nedeed to configure a custom project.
The requirement is that the client keeps in memory all the data necessary for this configuration and get back to the backend a big object so it can perform multiple insert/delete operation.
For example:
Let's say we have these models:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }        
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descritpion { get; set; }        
    public DateTime ValidityDateStart { get; set; }        
    public DateTime ValidityDateEnd { get; set; }        
}

public class ContractEmployee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Contract Contract { get; set; }
}
```

We said that the client manipulates data of all entities before returning to the backend, so i need a data structure to contain everything.
The problem is how to do it.
Should i make a simple collection of these entities?

```
public class Dto
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public List<Contract> ContractRegistry { get; set; }
    public List<ContractEmployee> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

The user can perform CRUD operation on every table.
In this case the client what send to the backend? 
The entire data? Just the rows that have been modified? And, in this case, how can i know what to do on the rows when i have to persist data in EF?

Should i set on a single row what operation perform?
Employee class becomes for example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }        
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public EnumOperation Operation { get; set; }  // Values: 0=Insert; 1=Modify; 2=Update; 3=Delete
}
```

I find this one a horrible way and i wouldn't consider it...

What is the best approach to manage this case?

Comment: The advantage of EF is manage all changes from memory and commit to database properly with the only API `SaveChanges`.  We have no need to worry if all changed committed.  it just works. I guess what your question is: how to cache changes in frontend and bulk-commit changes to backend?  yes?

Comment: @Dongdong The first thing is passing from Dto to entity these rows and then yes, the next problem will be bolk-commit the changes.